# Logout isn't working php

Tags: php, logout

I've been working on a very simple login system to understand the fundamentals of things, so there is no security yet or SQL. So i'm doing it via php at the minute. In my index page I have my login etc and on my home page I have my logout etc now I cannot get it to logout for some reason I thought I was about destroying the session but I must be wrong. Anyone know where I'm going wrong here.

**Index**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
        session_start();        
        $username = "admin";
        $password = "collins1";

    if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {
        header("Location: home.php");
    }

    if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
        if ($_POST['username'] == $username && $_POST['password'] == $password)
        {   
            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
            header("Location: home.php");
        }

    }
    else {
        echo "Username or Password incorrect please try again";
    }
?>

<html>
    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Login</title>

        <link href="../CSS/boilerplate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="../CSS/master.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

        <script src="../JAVASCRIPT/respond.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body link="black">
    <div class="gridContainer clearfix">

        <div id="borderDiv">

            <div id="headerDiv">
                <p>Welcome</p>
            </div>

            <div id="subHeaderDiv">
                <p>Please login to continue</p>
            </div>

            <form method="post" action="index.php">
                <div id="userNameLoginDiv">
                    <p>Username:</p>
                    <input type="text" name="username" size="12">
                </div>  

                <div id="userPasswordLoginDiv">
                    <p>Password:</p>
                    <input type="password" name="password" size="12">
                </div>

                <div id="loginBtnDiv">
                    <input id="button" type="submit" value="Login">
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Home**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
    session_start();

    if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) || $_SESSION['loggedin'] == false) {
        header("Location: index.php");
    }

    if (isset($_GET['logout'])){
    session_destroy();  
    }

?>


<html>
    <head>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

        <title>Home</title>
        <link href="../CSS/boilerplate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="../CSS/master.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

        <script src="../JAVASCRIPT/respond.min.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body link="black">

        <div class="gridContainer clearfix">

            <div id="headerDiv">
                <p>Home</p>
            </div>

            <a href="index.php?logout">Logout</a>
        </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Logout link: `index.php?logout`

Your index.php doesn't contain `session_destroy()` - you need to use `home.php?logout`. In your case you need to destroy the session before checking auth in home.php to get redirected to index.php

Comment: So I would need to move `if (isset($_GET['logout'])){
    session_destroy(); 
    }` So it is above `session_destroy`

Comment: Oh sorry I understand, got it working now thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Best way - There should be a logout page.
logout.php

```
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['loggedin']);
or
$_SESSION['loggedin']=false;
or session_destory();
header("Location:index.php");
die();
```